# Displaying collection items on mevn stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I have simple project about movie rating using mevn stack
this is my app look like :
[myapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXMF7.png)
this is the sample of picture:
[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1RNn.png)

This is my entire of my code :

```
<template>
 <v-timeline>
  <v-timeline-item color="indigo lighten-2" fill-dot right v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie._id">
  <span class="grey--text" slot="opposite">{{ movie.release_year }} ‧ {{ movie.genre }}</span>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="indigo lighten-2">
      <v-icon dark size="42" class="mr-3">
        movie
      </v-icon>
      <h2 class="display-1 white--text font-weight-light">{{ movie.name }}</h2>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex xs10>
          {{ movie.description }}
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs2>
          <v-icon size="64">movie</v-icon>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-card>
</v-timeline-item>
```

This is my javascript code :

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
 export default {
 name: 'Movies',
 data () {
 return {
  movies: [],
  show: false
  }
 },
  mounted () {
  this.fetchMovies()
  },
 methods: {
  async fetchMovies () {
    return axios({
      //display all movies
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8081/movies'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      this.movies = response.data.movies
    })
    .catch(() => {})
    }
   } 
  }
</script>
```

How to create condition to make different position just like my sample of picture, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a closing </v-timeline> tag?

Comment: And why the 'right' in <v-timeline-item>? That right aligns all items for me.

Comment: @Andrew1325 yes i have closing tag </v-timeline> sorry i left it, right class to make my all of collection placed at right side, and vice versa if change it using left class

Comment: That right class is aligning them all on one side. Try it without. Also if you want different colors on each movie you'll have to dynamically input them. If you're struggling copy the exact code from the vuetify site.

Comment: @Andrew1325 okay thank you, it was worked now case #closed